# How to extend an abstract class in a sub-package?

Tags: java, import, package, abstract-class, extends

I have an interface implemented by 2 abstract class, and I have to extends these class in a sub-package, but I don't know how to do it.

I have my class 1 in a package (summarized) :

```java
package com.p1;

abstract class Class1 implements InterfaceTest{
    private int x;

    public Class1(int x){
    }
}
```

And my second class in a sub-package :

```java
package com.p1.subPackage;

import com.p1.Class1; //which is not working cause its abstract

public class Class2 extends Class1{
    public Class2(){
        x = 5;
    }
}
```

How I am supposed to import this class?

Comment: It's not working because the class isn't `public`, not because the class is abstract. Having no visibility modifier means it's package-private. In other words, it's only visible to classes within the same package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in will help

Answer (score 1):

make the Class1 `public abstract` class.

```
public abstract class Class1 implements InterfaceTest{
```